# EC2 external inventory script fails because of ImportError: No module named ansible.module_utils

Tags: python, boto, ansible-inventory

My mac is running macOS 10.13, python 2.7.13 and 3.6.2

Ansible is 2.3.1.0 - http://prntscr.com/grjh34

When I'm trying to run EC2 external inventory script I'm getting **ImportError: No module named ansible.module_utils** - http://prntscr.com/grjhoq

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've deleted Ansible which was installed with brew and installed it with pip, that did the trick and everything works as expected now